# load() in SoundPool cannot be applied to: error - how do I correct this?

Tags: java, android, soundpool

I am trying to make a soundboard which has sliding activities. I have successfully managed to make sliding activities but when I try and load a sound into the .java file it gives me an error saying "load() in SoundPool cannot be applied to" the code within the two ** below is where the error is coming up.

```
package com.jonatboard.jonat.htssoundboard;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.SoundPool;

public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {

    SoundPool sclubb1;
    int clubb1Id;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one_layout,container,false);
        sclubb1 = new SoundPool(10,AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,0);
        clubb1Id = sclubb1.load **(this,R.raw.clubb1,1)**; }

    public void playSound1(View view) {
        sclubb1.play(clubb1Id, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a `return` as the first line of a method and code after that. I'm not a Java guy but in most languages that means that code never runs.